# Close Button on Drop down carts - better for UI/UX or not?

Tags: conversion, shopping-cart

The following websites have dropdown carts:

```
www.matchesfashion.com/mens
www.asos.com
```

In my opinion they work well. Once filled by the user hovering the basket link and the cart appears until the hover away. I am thinking of making the same but rather than hover, they click their basket and it appears - the basket box does not move until they click close button.

Why? It makes the user interact - they have to move their mouse, press the close each time; It is my opinion that this makes them feel as if they are in control of the shopping experience and it creates better conversions and more sales. Is this a correct assumption? Should such carts be given a close button or is the hover-to-close option more usable?

See my before and after examples.

[image]

Comment: That last statement is a pretty bold one, I don't think it's that easy.

Comment: I've edited your question because it wasn't really a question it was more a statement that you wanted people to agree with. This edit shows that you have seen one implementation method and are considering going with an alternative option that you are not sure is preferable rather than just stating that your option is the best up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to keep closing boxes can be annoying.

1. When the user adds to cart the box should appear and have it delay
   for about 1.5sec
2. If the user hovers over the BASKET button have the cart slide down - if they move their mouse away from the BASKET link button hide the cart.
3. If the user hovers over the BASKET button have the cart slide down - if they stay within the cart box

Comment: Where do you get your timings from? Why should it slide in/out rather than fade in / out? This comes across as your own personal preference rather than a specific user preference.